# MVC Modal Validation ErrorMessage for Decimal DataType with Globalization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation, data-annotations

I guess the topic explains the need pretty much. But I will try to explain a little more...

First of all I want to mention that I installed globalize js library with nuget. So in the decimal field, people can add numbers with "." and "," depending on their locale settings in the browser. That was the first catch I managed to solve.

The second problem is, showing the error messages according to the locale setting. I used resource files to make that happen, and that worked fine until I realized that some messages are not using the strings in the resource files. For example, when I write a letter instead of a number (I am talking about that decimal field), the error message is

```
The field Price must be a number.
```

I couldn't figure out how to change that until I saw some questions similar to mine. Some solved that problem with regular expressions. I could do that, but you see, I set up globalization all right for other things and now I have to decide if the user is gonna put "," or "." in the decimal field. I simply don't want to go that way.

Here is the code I used to create that field in the modal class

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Validation), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
[Display(Name = "Fiyat")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency, ErrorMessage = "Fiyat geçerli değil.")] // I know that
doesn't work, but couldn't really figure out why there is an error message for datatype at all.
[Range(0, 100, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Validation), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Range")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Can you please give me some ideas how to show the correct message (correct language using the resource files) when a user enters letters, or just use "," or "." when their locale doesn't let them?

Comment: Where you able to find a solution? I face the same issue....

Comment: No, not really. I decided to develop that project with angular, and all my error messages are created on client side now. I write there whatever I want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, I was facing the same issue and I ended up doing the following:

Use a regex just to know if this is a valid number (accepting both comma/dot as decimal separator for multiple cultures) and then leaving the Range dataannotation for testing if the number is really valid (use or not the comma/dot) and the range itself. 
Seems to be working just fine :)

```
[Display(Name = "TdPrime", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Somethings.Something))]       
[RegularExpression(@"-?(?:\d*[\,\.])?\d+", 
                ErrorMessageResourceName = "DataType_Number", 
                ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Validations))]       
[Range(0, 999.9999, 
          ErrorMessageResourceName = "RangeAttribute_ValidationError",
          ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Validations))]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.####}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal? TdPrime { get; set; }
```

It seems that you decided to use angular, but at least next time you will have one more solution to choose from :)

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your answer. I don't have time to validate this, but it seems logical and I guess I'll take your word for it :)

Comment: Hi @Dryadwoods, in your solution how do you integrate with the Globalization library for the custom error message? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882732/validate-number-with-globalize-or-with-dataannotation-in-mvc